# Calculate accumulative win loss percentage

Tags: mysql

I currently have a list of all games played by team in which the list produces the team name, score, opponent name and score and either a W (Won), L (Lost) or D (Draw) which are all derived from my table "MatchDetails2017".  What I want to do is display the cumulative win percentage after each game.

I have spent a few hours trying to find help online and have hit a brick wall.

```
SELECT Game, WL, ((SELECT COUNT(WL) FROM MatchDetails2017 WHERE Team = 'TeamName' AND WL = 'W')/COUNT(*))*100   
FROM MatchDetails2017
WHERE Team = 'TeamName'
GROUP BY Game
```

For example I want the data to display like this...

```
Game|Result|Win%
    1|W|100.00
    2|W|100.00
    3|W|100.00
    4|L|75.00
    5|D|60.00
    6|W|66.67
```

This is my results I am currently getting...

```
1 W 5200.0000
2 W 5200.0000
3 W 5200.0000
4 L 5200.0000
5 D 5200.0000
6 W 5200.0000
```

Comment: Your query and sample data so not line up so nicely.  Please fix your data.

Comment: Do not have a table per year.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work the `COUNT(*)` to compute total games also needs to be over only the preceding games, so you need to bring it into your subquery. You also need to restrict the subquery to only games including and preceding the current one:

```
SELECT Game, 
       WL AS Result,
       (SELECT SUM(WL = 'W') / COUNT(*) FROM MatchDetails2017 m2 WHERE m2.Game <= m1.Game AND m2.Team = m1.Team) * 100 AS `Win%`
FROM MatchDetails2017 m1
WHERE Team = 'TeamName'
```

Output:

```
Game    Result  Win%
1       W       100
2       W       100
3       W       100
4       L       75
5       D       60
6       W       66.6667
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9PhqMndzgL6W7cq96GAT1T/1)

Note that this query takes advantage of the fact that MySQL treats boolean values as either 1 or 0 in a numeric context, so we can `SUM(WL = 'W')` to get the total number of wins.

Comment: Brilliant!  Works perfect - thanks Nick  - I just added WHERE Team = 'Teamname' at the end

Comment: @waflfootyfacts sorry - forgot that as I only had one team in my sample. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I've just added the code to my site, but its causes a timeout for any team with over 150 rows, most teams have over 1500-25-- rows.  The query takes 5 seconds or so in my cPanel.  Any idea how to make the query more efficient?

Comment: @waflfootyfacts that seems very odd. I've created a test case [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9PhqMndzgL6W7cq96GAT1T/3) with 3 teams with 360 games each and the query takes about 150ms for each team. That can be improved by adding indexes on Team, Game and also Team, Game, WL and you can get more by changing `m2.team = m1.team` to `m2.team = 'TeamName'`. It does go up exponentially though with more games though, is there any way you can limit the number of games you want to do the query on?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+ we can try using `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    TeamID,
    Game,
    WL,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WL = 'W' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY TeamId ORDER BY Game) /
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TeamId) win_pct
FROM MatchDetails2017
ORDER BY
    TeamID,
    Game;
```